# How do I import/integrate Phabricator (Maniphest) with Mantis

Tags: mantis, phabricator, maniphest

I am interested in implementing Phabricator to manage our software development. We are currently using Mantis 1.2.11 as our bug tracking tool. 
Is there any guide or tool to integrate or import Mantis bug reports with Phabricator that I can use?
Regards
Puneet

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the approach of integrating rather than migrating, mainly because we've written some custom report generators on top of Mantis which I don't see how to easily fit into Phabricator (which seems to be aimed exclusively to the needs of developers, not their managers and other teams they need to interact with).

On the Phabricator side, I configured bugtraq.url and bugtraq.logregex for linking to mantis bug ids mentioned in checkin comments.

On the Mantis side, I hacked the [SourceWebSVN](https://github.com/mantisbt-plugins/source-integration) plugin (you can substitute SourceGitWeb or SourceHgWeb as appropriate) to link to revisions in Diffusion instead of WebSVN, and also the [LinkText](http://ascend4.org/Automatic_URL_linking_to_MediaWiki_and_ViewVC_from_Mantis) plugin for linking to other objects in Phabricator.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I don't mind the integration approach. I'll look into this and see if I can get this going at my end.

Comment: If you are still looking at this, I've just uploaded my generalisation of the LinkText mantis plugin at https://github.com/make-all/AutoLink.